# Schedule a scala file using oozie?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, oozie

How do I run/schedule a .scala file which I run using spark-shell command using oozie?

I run this file using ***spark-shell -i combined.scala***
    command!

I was wondering if something specific like how we schedule pig jobs in oozie is present here!

As per David's suggestion I have created the xml:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.2' name='oozie-java-spark-wf'>
   <start to='java-spark' />

   <action name='java-spark'>
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <name>Spark Patent Citation</name>
            <class>org.apache.spark.repl.Main</class>
            <jar></jar>
            <arg>-i</arg>
            <arg>${nameNode}/user/hdfs/scala_file/combined.scala</arg>
</spark>


    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
      <message>Spark Java PatentCitation failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I am getting an error like this:

Error Code  JA018
Error Message   Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, null

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Spark Action for Oozie:

[Oozie Spark Action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html)

spark-shell is just a wrapper around `org.apache.spark.repl.Main` -- just specify that as the `SPARK MAIN CLASS` and pass in `-i` and `combined.scala` as `<arg/>` values.

Comment: The jar element indicates a comma separated list of jars or python files. Not ".scala" file

Comment: I edited my answer -- spark-shell is just a wrapper around an underlying Java class.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response David :)

Comment: No thanks needed -- just up-vote and accept my answer. ;)

Comment: Hi David what will go as this param? <jar>[SPARK DEPENDENCIES JAR / PYTHON FILE]</jar> @David

Comment: Do you have dependencies in your script? Like, does it require specific JAR files -- add them there.